# C# LINQ in the Select

Tags: linq

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Select((n,i) =>{ return n*i;})
```

what does the "i" get in every time?

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 999).Select((n,i,j) =>{ return n*i*j;})
```

why cant I add "j"?

Comment: `i` is the index of the element in the sequence starting with 0. Actually it's [this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) you're calling. There's no third overload with three arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Select` overload accepting a lambda with two parameters will take the first parameter from the sequence, and the second is the index of the element.

In your example `i` will always be `n-1`, so there is not much use of the second parameter. When working with non-trivial sequences or sequences of non-numeric types it can sometimes be an advantage to have the order number of the element available in the select expression.

There is no three parameter version. That's why `(n,i,j)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to the Select() extension method on IEnumerable has two forms. One takes one argument (the current element of the enumeration) and the second two arguments (the current element and the index). There is no version that takes three arguments. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 1):

The i is the name you've used for the index of the element you are currently projecting. You can't specify a third parameter because there is no overload of Select which defines a delegate that takes three parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can either build new elements on the basis of value (`Select(n)`) or on the basis of value and index (`Select(n, i)`). `Select()` with three parameters is not defined.

Compare: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select